# How user space programs uses device drivers functionality?

Tags: operating-system, drivers

Ex-My Webcam has face detection feature. I don't think this functionality can be achieved by standard device driver model .like Linux assumes everything as file and uses operations like read ,write etc for communicating to driver. So how user space programs uses these functionalities of device drivers?

Comment: That depends on your webcam and its driver. If there is a driver at all, you need to read up on how the functionality is exposed. The "everything is a file" model Linux uses is very flexible and allows for a very high degree of generality and abstraction. I don't know much about face detection, but I am sure a file serves well for interaction with the webcam. [This](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/hardware.html) looks promising.

Comment: And how can I check that?

Comment: What do you want to check precisely? I suggest you read the article I referred to in my prior comment, it contains a description about how the drivers are loaded and hardware-specific info on the drivers.

Comment: As an aside, please be more specific in your questions. This one is overly broad and it is not clear if you are asking about device drivers in general or your particular webcam (the exact name of it would be helpful). A terser title also improves things. Reading [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is probably a good idea.

Comment: How to know what functionalities are  exposed by the driver?

Comment: Sorry for confusion I am asking about device drivers on general webcam was just an example.

Comment: As I said, this totally depends on the particular driver. Search for a driver for your device and if there is one, read its  documentation. Look up `ioctl` as well.